# Sound feedback while in terminal/text editor?

Tags: xorg, audio, keyboard, text-to-speech, accessibility

When I am typing in the terminal, often I am typing in commands or code without necessarily looking at the screen. Probably this would annoy many people, but for me I would like audible feedback from my typing, so I know when I have mistyped, with alphabetic characters having a certain sound, special characters having their own (or something along those lines).

This has overlap with accessibility concerns, but Outside of Orca, I don't know of much in that area, or whether there is some previous project that is similar... I know that ‘echo -ne '\007' will create a system sound but I don't know how I would hook that into reading a specific character from my input device.

Imagine if you had a terminal open and you had it set to make a soft, but specific noise every time you typed '}'. that way if you mistyped and the shift hadn't registered, resulting in a ']', you would know right away

(in particular my hands have very bad arthritis so it is sometimes harder to fully depress a key so it makes debug a pain and Id rather "stay in the flow" of knowing to listen for a different sound rather than looking up at the screen every couple seconds, but a full on screen reader that reads everything would be a pain in the ass)

Comment: I can think of several ways to script it: Have `evtest` run on the right `/dev/input/` device for your keyboard, parse output for keypresses you want. Or on the X level, use `xmacrorec` in a similar way. In `emacs`, bind keys to emit a sound in addition to `self-insert`. Etc.

Comment: don't know if buckle would do it for you if you use ubuntu. produces the old ibm keyboard clanking sounds. `sudo apt install bucklespring`

Comment: perhaps some accessibility software could be used to speak out what you type, and then you could change the sounds if you want to something more suitable for your needs?